# Erro ao executar projeto Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, diretório, angular-material

estou tentando executar uma aplicação Angular no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, mas estou passando por alguns problemas.
Clonei o repositório do projeto, executei o npm install, e ao executar um ng serve, o projeto simplesmente não abre no navegador, me retornando o erro Cannot GET/, e no meu console eu tenho recebido diversos erros.
Acredito que o problema esteja na estruturação de pastas do projeto, porém já fiz diversas mudanças, pesquisei na internet como fazer, e nenhum resultado positivo até agora, seguem os prints da estrutura e os códigos da estrutura.

Meu arquivo angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ngx-admin-demo": {
    "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "aot": true,
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        "rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls": true,
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/favicon.png",
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "node_modules/leaflet/dist/images",
            "output": "/assets/img/markers"
          }
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "node_modules/typeface-exo/index.css",
          "node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css",
          "node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
          "node_modules/socicon/css/socicon.css",
          "node_modules/nebular-icons/scss/nebular-icons.scss",
          "node_modules/pace-js/templates/pace-theme-flash.tmpl.css",
          "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
          "src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.min.js",
          "node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js",
          "node_modules/echarts/dist/extension/bmap.min.js",
          "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js",
          "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.min.js",
          "node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js",
          "node_modules/echarts/dist/extension/bmap.min.js",
          "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "node_modules/typeface-exo/index.css",
          "node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css",
          "node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
          "node_modules/socicon/css/socicon.css",
          "node_modules/nebular-icons/scss/nebular-icons.scss",
          "node_modules/pace-js/templates/pace-theme-flash.tmpl.css",
          "src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss"
        ],
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/favicon.png",
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "node_modules/leaflet/dist/images",
            "output": "/assets/img/markers"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "typeCheck": true,
        "exclude": []
      }
    }
  }
},
"ngx-admin-demo-e2e": {
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "",
  "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:serve"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
        ],
        "exclude": []
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"defaultProject": "ngx-admin-demo",
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
  "prefix": "ngx",
  "style": "scss"
},
"@schematics/angular:directive": {
  "prefix": "ngx"
}
},
"cli": {
"analytics": "cba96cbd-ba0e-4397-94dc-95e78f3503d4"
}
}
```

Abaixo o print da minha estrutura de projeto e erro do console...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

**Can't bind to since it isn't a known property of**

Normalmente ocorre quando vocês esquece de importar o modulo que contem o componente ou diretive que esta tentando usar.

Quanto a **Can't resolve in**

Você deveria checar todos os seus imports e tambêm `baseUrl` no tscofig.json